# 3x3 Average filter C

Tags: c#

I'm trying to complete a project in C# and I ran into a problem. I'm given an image and I'm asked to apply a 3x3 average filter.

```
Byte[,] image0 = new Byte[ySize,xSize]; // global input image
Byte[,] image1 = new Byte[ySize,xSize]; // global output image
private void AvFilter3x3_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) 
{ Int32 sum, x, xx, xxx, y, yy, yyy;
  for ( y=1; y < ySize-1; y++ )   //for each row    except the first and last
  { for ( x=1; x < xSize-1; x++ ) //for each column except the first and last
    { sum = 0;
      for ( yy=-1; yy <= 1; yy++ )  //upper, mid and lower indicees
      { yyy = y + yy;
        for ( xx=-1; xx <= 1; xx++ )//left,  mid and right indicees
        { xxx = x + xx;
          sum += image0[yyy,xxx];   //add them up
        } //====== end for (int xx... ================
      } //======== end for (int yy... ================
      image1[y,x] = Convert.ToByte( (float)sum/9f ); //divide by 9 and round
    } //============ end for (int x... =====================
  } //============== end for (int y... =====================
}
```

Comment: `yplane[j][i]==(float)sum;` -- What are you expecting that line to do?

Comment: If `j<240` and `b<j+3` then on the last loop `b = j+2 = 239 + 2 = 241`, which is out of range for `yplane[240]`. Same for `a`. Also when `b=j-1` and `j=0`, then `b=-1` which is a negative index.... Same for `a`.

Comment: @Shawn yplane[j][i]==(float)sum/9; fixed it

Comment: Still the same question.

Comment: implement the average value of the 3x3 box at the center i guess @Shawn

Comment: You are assigning a float to a char. That won't work.

Comment: It also means: _turn on warnings of your compiler!_.

Comment: not assigning :) he's only testing '=='. However I'm curious why the file changes ... unless he's not reading and writing the whole file.

Comment: also there's a point to ynew. it depends on the aim ... but you probably don't want to modify your input

Comment: @PaulOgilvie What I'm hoping OP will notice is that he's not assigning anything with that line.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 different planes Y U V, you need to do the 3x3 processing for all three which will blur the image and reduce the noise pixel

Comment: Note that his u and v panes are just half the size of his y plane. Error? Typo?

Comment: the y,u,v array declarations were given by professor

Answer (score 0):

Again let me stress what Shawn is trying to make you see (here, as I cannot comment):

```
yplane[j][i]==(float)sum/9;
```

is not an assignment...

'==' is not an assignment.

```
sum = sum + yplane[b][a];
```

for example, is.